# C# Get Binary Search To Display All Duplicate Values In Array

Tags: c#, arrays, duplicates, binary-search

If I search through my sorted array it only displays one of the values even if there are multiple of the same value in the array. I don't want it to tell me how many duplicates there are, I want it to display all of the duplicate values in the array that I search for. Or is there are different search I need to use to do this?

So if I have array1{1,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,6} and I search for 5 I want it to output:

```
5
5
5
5
```

This is is my code with binary search.

```
 public class search
    {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Arrays are created here. e.g. array1{1,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,6}

        int Input;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number you would like to search for.");
    Input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int y = BinarySearch(array1, Input);
Console.WriteLine("array1 {0} : array2{1} : array3 {2} : array4 {3} : array5 {4}",array1[y], array2[y], array3[y], array4[y], array5[y]);
}       

 public static int BinarySearch(double[] Array, int Search)
        {
            int x = Array.Length;
        int low = 0;
        int high = x - 1;

        while (low <= high)
        {
            while (low <= high)
            {
                int mid = (low + high) / 2;
                if (Search < Array[mid])
                {
                    high = mid - 1;
                }
                else if (Search > Array[mid])
                {
                    low = mid + 1;
                }
                else if (Search == Array[mid])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", Search);
                    return mid;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0} was not found.", Search);
        }
        return high;
      }
}
```

Comment: You have `return` statement on first match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can use binary search for this. But your code is kinda weird. Because when you find the first element here `else if (Search == array[mid]) ...` you immediately return from the function and never call it again. That is why you get only one result.

To make it work, when you find such element, you need to search in the array through indices low ... mid-1 and then through indices mid+1 ... high.

Here is the code, but I strongly advise you not just to copy that and maybe try to rewrite this into while loop (every recursion can be rewritten as a loop)

```
static void BinarySearch(int[] array, int low, int high, int searchedValue)
    {
        if (low > high)
            return;
            int mid = (low + high) / 2;
            if (searchedValue < array[mid])
            {
                high = mid - 1;
                BinarySearch(array, low, high, searchedValue); 
            }
            else if (searchedValue > array[mid])
            {
                low = mid + 1;
                BinarySearch(array, low, high, searchedValue);
            }
            else if (searchedValue == array[mid])
            {
                Console.WriteLine(array[mid]);
                BinarySearch(array, low, mid - 1, searchedValue);
                BinarySearch(array, mid + 1, high, searchedValue);               
            }            
    }
```